# how to navigate to same browser window from ios app using "openUrl" method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, url-scheme, openurl

I have configured url schemes in my applications info.plist
so when i type url scheme in browser my app is getting launched , now requirement is , how to go back to same window of the browser from which my app invoked when i click some button in my app .

```
-(IBAction) someButtonAction
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xyz"]]
}
```

it's opening new tab , is there any way to open same window .

thanks in advance .

Comment: It seems like no, because you don't tell anything directly to Safari, only if it itself has URL Scheme. Maybe it would be better to send some parameters to restore context of previous tab?

Comment: i would add the url as a parameter to the url scheme

Comment: i agree , but how google maps ios app is doing that ? are they using any third party or something

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger i didn't get ur point , can you please explain

Comment: @Azat can you tell me how , i dnt have any idea about restoring context.

Comment: @RIYAZ I mean implement your webpage to take input parameters to restore its appearance at it was when you leaved the browser. And could you tell please how can I see that Google maps returns to exactly previous tab?

Comment: To achieve this you need to Use Webview

Answer (score 0):

You have to append parameter something like callbackUrl:

So the "my.trustidentity" is the url scheme that defined in your ios app, the callbackUrl you need to parse and save in ios app for later on to call OpenURL to go back the browser.

`<a href="my.trustidentity://https://testserver/usage/?callbackUrl=http://192.168.1.163/trustidentity"><img src="qrcode.png" />`